# Finding first n prime numbers and insert them to a database (by connecting to phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

> Write a PHP program that finds the first N prime numbers and writes
>   them to a database with two fields (column ID and value). The N value
>   is entered by the user.The result should be a page including a table
>   with the contents of the database.

The array with the first n numbers are correctly showing on the first line, but I when I try to insert the array into the database incorrect values are stored. Instead of storing and displaying the values '2', '3', '5', '7' in the 'value' column, [as you can see in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcbKr.png), the table consists of values of '2' instead of the actual values from the array. Any suggestions what may be wrong?

Code in html page:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="nform.php">
<p>Finding the first n prime numbers</p>
<p>
    <label>Enter a value for N:
    <input name="n" type="text"">
    </label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</p>
</form>
```

Code in external php file (nform.php):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//Finding first n prime numbers:
function printPrimeNumbers($n){

    $isPrime = true;
    $num = 3;
    $primeNumbers = array();

    if($n >= 1){
        $primeNumbers[] = 2;
    }

    if($n > 1){
        for($i = 2; $i<=$n;){
            for($j = 2; $j <= sqrt($num); $j++){
                if($num % $j == 0){
                    $isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if($isPrime) { //if $num is prime number
                $primeNumbers[] = $num;
                $i++;
            }
            $isPrime = true;
            $num++;
        }
    }
    return $primeNumbers;
}
$n = $_POST["n"];
$primeNum = printPrimeNumbers($n);

echo "First $n prime numbers are: ", implode(",", $primeNum)."<P>"; //array to string conversion
$primeNumStr = implode(",", $primeNum);


//Connecting to MySQL
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SHOW DATABASES";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, 'p_numbers');
if(!$db_selected){
    $query = "CREATE DATABASE p_numbers";

    //Creating table 'numbers' with 2 fields
    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers(value_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, value INT NOT NULL)";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $query) == FALSE){
        die(mysqli_error($link));
    }
} else {
    mysqli_select_db($link, 'p_numbers');
}
//Inserting user input values into table 'numbers'
$query = "INSERT INTO numbers(value) VALUES ('".$primeNumStr."')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);

if(mysqli_query($link, $query) == FALSE) {
    die(mysqli_error($link));
} else {
    print("Entered value has been successfully stored.");
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>

<p>Table of stored values:</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!--Selecting stored values from table 'numbers' and inserting them into a HTML table-->
<?php $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "p_numbers");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM numbers");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
    echo $row[0]." ".$row[1]." "."<br/>";
}

mysqli_close($link); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're inserting a comma-separated string of numbers into a single row, and so it's being converted to the first number in the string (i.e. up until the first comma). You need to loop over your `$primeNum` array and insert them individually.

Comment: @iainn They can be inserted collectively, but as separate rows.

Comment: To store a string use one of [the string data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-types.html), not INT.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO numbers(value) VALUES ('".$primeNumStr."')";
```

`$primeNumStr` is a comma-separated list; but because you're surrounding it in quotes, it's treated as a string. The simple solution is to remove those quotes. This should be sufficient for a learning exercise. In the real world you'd loop through the array, inserting each individually with precautions taken to protect against SQL injection.

A couple of other notes. You don't need to keep closing and re-creating the connection object. Just use the same one for the duration of the script. I'd recommend using PDO, if you have a choice in your class. If you're stuck with mysqli, you should at least be learning the object-oriented interface, which is less verbose and error-prone. And, you should be separating your PHP from your HTML as much as possible. Ideally in a separate file, but at least keep your PHP at the top of the file and HTML at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but THANKS, this solved the problem. :)